# JS prototype class not all properties are accessible

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have defined a prototype class with few properties and methods and for some reason I cannot access all the properties in some cases (mainly when callbacks are involved).

Here is my code (removed some lines to make it clearer)

```
var Lobby = function (preloader, serverConn) {
  // Hold a reference to EventBus
  this.serverConn = serverConn;
  this.preloader = preloader;

  this.session_id = null;
  this.scheduleItemService = new ScheduledItemService(this.preloader);

  // Instantiate lobby stage
  this.stage = new createjs.Stage("lobbyCanvas");
};

Lobby.prototype._renderLobbyImages = function(stage, scheduleItemService) {
   // at this point, 'stage' and 'scheduleItemService' are valid!
  ..
  // onScheduledItemClick callback function
  this.scheduleItemService.render(stage, this._onScheduledItemClick);
}

Lobby.prototype._onScheduledItemClick = function(event) {
  (function(inst) {
  inst.serverConn.asyncSend(
    'game.lobby',
    { 'action' : 'claim_scheduled_item',
        'session_id' : inst.session_id, **//Here, 'inst.session_id' is DEFINED!**
    },
    function (error, reply) {
      **// Here, both 'stage' and 'scheduleItemService' are UNDEFINED! WHY?!?!**
      inst.scheduleItemService.startCountdown(inst.stage);
    }
   });
  })(this);
}

ScheduledItemService.prototype.render = function(stage, onScheduledItemClick) {
  var scheduled_item = new createjs.Bitmap(preloader.getResult("scheduled_item_img"));
..
..
  scheduled_item.addEventListener('click', onScheduledItemClick);
..
}
```

Why this.session_id is defined in 'this' while 'stage' and 'scheduleItemService' are not defined?? these 3 are properties of Lobby class...

I tried browsing in 'this' pointer and I really couldn't find 'stage' nor 'scheduleItemService'.

I'm missing something, right?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Where's the prototype here?

Comment: why no `this` on those? i thinks you need to use "this.stage" and "this.scheduleItemService", since "this.session_id" works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scheduleItemService` variable is out of scope here

```
function (error, reply) {
      scheduleItemService.startCountdown(stage);
}
```

The thing is even if you did not use Promises, this code would still fail. If you want to define the `renderLobbyImages` and `onScheduledItemClick` as prototype methods, you'd have to write

```
Lobby.prototype.renderLobbyImages = function(){
    // this refers to a Lobby instance
    this.scheduleItemService.render(stage, this.onScheduledItemClick);
}

Lobby.prototype.onScheduledItemClick = function(){
    // this refers to a lobby instance
}
```

You must also use the use `this` keyword in the `onScheduledItemClick`.

Then, inside the promise callback you defined, the "`this`" keyword does not point back to the instance. That's why you are getting errors with your code. Inside this callback, the `this` changes.

To fix this, before the callback, store a temporary variable to the "`this`, here I named it `scope`". You can use this `scope` the same way you use `this`.

```
Lobby.prototype.onScheduledItemClick = function(event) {
  // this refers to a lobby instance
  var scope = this;
  this.serverConn.asyncSend(
    'game.lobby',
    { 
        'action'     : 'claim_scheduled_item',
        'session_id' : scope.session_id.bind(scope), // Here scope instead of this. But you could use this as not inside callback. I used scope just for consistency
    },
    function (error, reply) {
      // this does NOT refer to a lobby instance. You must use scope
      scope.scheduleItemService.startCountdown(stage);
    }
});
```

---

Edit 1

After your code edit, I can still see some errors.

I see that in your `Lobby.prototype._onScheduledItemClick`, you are using a `(inst)` variable, `this.serverConn.asyncSend`, it should be `inst.serverConn.asyncSen`

--

Edit 2

Another problem with your code is the callback. The scope is not passed along. You have to "bind" your callback with a scope. This is used using [function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind);

So now, your line looks like :

```
this.scheduleItemService.render(stage, this._onScheduledItemClick.bind(this));
```

This will make it so that when your callback is called, the "`this`" variable will have the value of the argument you pass in `bind`.

Comment: if all that's the case, then why would `this.session_id` work in the first function?

Comment: I think it's because the method was called with either apply/call/bind.

Comment: (i think OP simply forget to type `this.` in the 2nd function...)

Comment: The secret lies in the scheduleItemService.render method :)

Comment: The thing is the this in both methods can refer to anything. If the OP wants to use this, the methods should either be on the prototype or the constructor. Otherwise, they must always be called with bind/call/apply, or affect the global. Or it's an error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those should be prototype methods. Could be wrong

Comment: making method prototype is like making them public, right? that why I didn't make it prototype - I wanted to keep it "private" methods.

Comment: There is no such thing as private / public methods in JS. Adding a method to the prototype means that all objects that have Lobby as prototype will be able to access those methods with `this.method`

Comment: I can see from your profile that you come from Java. Think of javascript's prototype methods as public methods. If you want to "indicate" that a method is private, a convention in javascript is to prefix the method name with "_". So, in this case, `Lobby.prototype._renderLobbyImages` and `Lobby.prototype._onScheduledItemClick()` will tell you / users of your code that these are not public methods and should be used knowingly.

Comment: :-) Thanks - I will try this.

Comment: I changed the code to work with prototype, but still doesn't yield any results. I edit the code to reflect my changes, please take a look...

Comment: What does console.log(event) yields ?

Comment: And what is the code of scheduleItemService.render ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98838/discussion-between-shvalb-and-ludo).

Comment: Thank you for your help!! you're amazing!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck. Please accept the answer if it was satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you aren't prefixing your things with `this`. Unlike some other languages, `this` is not optional in JavaScript.

When you enter a new function call, `this` is redefined. You'll want to save a reference to it.

`this` is defined as the parent of the called function. Therefore it changes each time a function is called. Here's what people often do:

```
Something.prototype.foo = function() {
    var self = this;
    doSomething(function() {
        // now this has changed, but self still references the original this
   });
};
```

Comment: @dandavis Therein lies a second problem. `this` is not optional in JavaScript.